# Trackbar with fixed value point distance even if its maxvalue change

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, trackbar

how to do a trackbar with fixed trackbar value distance point even if its width change along with its maxValue in C# winform.

I am trying to do a video player so that i can specifically point to the particular part of a video clip even if i play a lengthy video. i could to see each tick part while playing.

Trackbar width can change that doesn't matter using scroll bar to the panel, but i need a fixed value distance with minimum two unit gap.

```
        this.trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
        this.trackBar1.Maximum = <variable>;
```

Comment: Don't get well what your problem is, do you mean your `trackBar1.Maximum` can change **depending on the video duration**?

Comment: yes King king, width could change along with the MaxValue

Comment: What's problem with that variability? If you want to **jump** to some **scene/frame** in the **video**, you may find some **method** to do so, why bothering the `TrackBar` here?

Comment: if running a very lengthy file, i won't able to each tick exact point in the trackbar control

Comment: That problem also happens to the **famous players** like **Windows Media Player**, you don't have any better choice. BTW, you should use a **smooth slider** instead of **ticked slider** for using in a `media player`.

Comment: what is the case for playing a pic slide show

Comment: The length of your `TrackBar` is limited, you can't find anyway to allow user to tick the exact position, unless you can **zoom** your TrackBar. However you may want to implement it differently such as by some **next/forward and prev/backward buttons** and some textbox to type in the `point of time/frame index` to jump to.